# Updating data with swift 3 firebase (all fields) - XCODE 8 (2017)

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I wrestled a lot with this issue, so I will provide the answer in case someone else has an issue with it

Answer (score 0):

The way swift seems to update it's nodes is via "replace and add"
The examples of firebase's website just did not seem to work, so I figured it out through trial and error

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    self.txtBankName.text = oBank.BankName;
    self.txtBankType.text = oBank.BankType;
    self.txtBankBalance.text = String(describing: oBank.BankBalance!)
    fireBaseKey = oBank.fireBaseKey;
    lblFireBaseKey.text = fireBaseKey;

    refBanks  = Database.database().reference().child("Bank")

}

func updateBankFirebase()
{
    let key = oBank.fireBaseKey
    let bankBalance:String? = self.txtBankBalance.text;
    let updateBank = ["BankName":oBank.BankName!,"BankType":self.txtBankType.text!,"BankBalance":bankBalance,"id":key!]
    refBanks.child(key!).setValue(updateBank)
    lblFireBaseKey.text = "Record updated..."
};
```